# Is it possible to make changes to code without changing the information reported by `git blame`?

Tags: git

Suppose I had a git repository with code from multiple users, but some of them don’t adhere to the indentation guidelines and use spaces instead of tabs. It would be easy to change this, but by cleaning up their code, `git blame` becomes less useful, since then I’d be blamed for other people’s code.

I’ve seen that one can specify the commit’s author and date using the respective flags, but this solution isn’t ideal to me, since I’d have to iterate over the users and change each user’s indentation in turn. I’d also have to find out the original commit date of the changed line in order to use the `--date` flag.

I also know that `git blame -w` ignores such whitespace changes, but I’d like to make the changes transparent. I find it cumbersome to use `-w` whenever i `blame`. (And as a sidenote, I doubt that the others will remember to use the flag when extracting information from `blame`.) This approach will also break down if the changes aren’t related to just whitespace (e.g. exchanging single quotes with double quotes).

Is it possible to make changes to the tracked files in git *without being considered the author of the changed lines and, ideally, without changing the original commit’s date?*

Comment: You could probably use `git config user.name` (and `user.email`). In any case, I'd assert this is an immoral solution since you're lying about who's actually making the changes.  If the style guide is important, don't accept commits that violate it.  If you're using centralized source control, install a hook that rejects these commits when somebody tries to push.

Comment: @StephenNewell Changing my git config is basically identical to using the `--author` flag (if I’m not mistaken) and yields the “I have to find out the original author beforehand” problem. Refusing such pushes *avoids* such a problem, but cannot be used to *fix* it.

Still I appreciate your input.

Comment: If you are allowed to rewrite history, you can do an interactive rebase and change the commits in question. Afaik an amend shouldn't change the author, this does open up a whole other can of worms though (since any tags will need to be remade and users might get merge issues when they pull the next time).

Comment: @fredrik I see two problems with your approach. First, in order to do an interactive rebase, I’d first have to generate a list of all “faulty” commits, and then select them manually for re-writing, and then edit each one individually*. This will be a lot of work. (If there existed a way to maintain the commit information from before my cleanup, I could just iterate over every file in the repo and replace the offending strings.) Second, rewriting history is scary. — *Or that is what I understood after reading https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Comment: @bleistift2 - Your question fundamentally involves rewriting history.  The only way to avoid that is to not do what you're asking.

Comment: How about solving the problem at the root? Agree on a whitespace style with the rest of the team and stick to it for all code modified henceforth. You can use Git hooks to help enforce that style (at commit or push time).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I disagree that this problem “*fundamentally* involves rewriting history.” I thought a possible solution to be just another commit which rectifies the code, but without the authorship information. Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to be how git works.

Comment: @Jubobs If the team could stick to the guide, I wouldn’t be in this position. Often these changes are introduced inadvertently by changing IDEs or by new team members. As with StephenNewell’s comment, installing a server-side hook can only prevent a guideline violation, not fix one.

Comment: @bleistift2 I understand, but I must agree with Oliver. If you can convince the team that the mixture of whitespace must be dealt with at once, freeze development and fix all the whitespace everywhere. The blame information will not be all gone, just more painful to tap into, and [3rd-party tools](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/recursive-blame) exist to remedy that. But don't try to cover your tracks: whitespace changes _are_ code changes—not to mention that, in many languages, whitespace is significant. When you're done, then enforce a whitespace style using Git hooks.

Comment: @bleistift2 You will need to find each "faulty" commit however you want to do it as long as you want to preserve the blame. There's no way of making a "transparent" commit, which means you either rewrite the history or impersonate each user in turn - fixing their problems. For both solutions you need to know which commits are at fault, so that you can either edit it or extract the author.

Comment: set up an alias?

Comment: @fredrik I think the two comments of yours make an answer worth accepting, especially the very concise “There’s no way of making a ‘transparent’ commit.”

Comment: I would run a script that replaces all the irregular tabs and update the code in a single dedicated commit. It doesn't really matter your name is there as the author of the code. It's clearly trackable what was done. It's just important not to mix other code changes with this fix in the same commit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this core git feature out yet, but regardless, in the second half of this answer, I say a very different strategy (GitLens) that I have tested well...

Git version 2.23 came out with a feature that can address your needs. You can specify a file that has a list of commits to ignore, when doing git blame.

Steps:

1. Make one or many regular commit(s) that have code-formatting changes, only.

   - As a side note: I recommend generating a commit like that, by using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/). (That is a tool that lets you run a command like `npx prettier -w --single-quote **/*` to format your files. WARNING: that particular command will likely change/improve most of the files in the folder you run it in, AND it will follow any smlinks you have in that folder (if you use smlinks) to change files in those other, liked folders. (You must install [Node](https://nodejs.org) to use `npx`.))
2. Follow the directions on https://akrabat.com/ignoring-revisions-with-git-blame/ to ignore those commit(s) when doing git blame.

*Optional* bonus step: read the comment someone made on [that](https://akrabat.com/ignoring-revisions-with-git-blame/) article that says how to get the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension of [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to pay attention to the file that lists the commits to ignore. Never use `git blame` on a command line ever again, and just use GitLens's git history tools.

- Extra-tangental tips about GitLens:

  - Be sure to put the `"gitlens.blame.ignoreWhitespace": true,` setting/line in your `.vscode/settings.json` file. (That file is for the vscode settings for everyone working on that project.)
  - GitLens offers many nice ways to see git blame, but when I search git history, most of the time a shallow git blame that just shows me the last editor of a line isn't powerful enough for my needs. So, when I want to see the history of a particular line, across several commits, I use the left panel. Be sure to press the little button shown here (it doesn't show up till you mouse over it) [image: vscode screenshot of button to toggle looking at git blame history of an entire file or for a single line] to toggle from showing git history of that whole file to showing the git history for just the line your cursor is on, and to *follow file renames* reliably. **THIS WORKS SO WELL, I DON'T EVEN NEED TO DO THE STUFF IN** https://akrabat.com/ignoring-revisions-with-git-blame/ .
  - When doing the stuff mentioned in the previous bullet point, I also find that I need to use the Pin History Button a *lot* [image: pin history button screenshot]. I will tell you the magically efficient steps I follow to use it. I know the steps I have listed below look long, but they only take about 1 minute to do, once you know the steps. Here's the steps:

    1. Look at the file in VS Code with the GitLens extension installed. (Hopefully you are doing this already because vscode is awesome and relatively lightweight.)
    2. Place your cursor on the line you want want to know the history of.
    3. Make sure you have line history mode toggled on. (See the first screenshot.)
    4. Toggle on the Pin History Button
    5. Click on a commit, in the list of commits right there. Click on a couple, until you find the oldest one that *immediately* shows you, in the *middle* of your screen, a diff that looks good/relevant to the line you care about (usually the top commit in the list).
    6. Place your cursor on the version of the line you care about on the *left* side of the diff.
    7. Press the Pin History Button *twice*, to toggle it off, then back on.
    8. Go back to Step 5, and repeat, until you find the commit that introduced that nasty bug into your beautiful code, so you can know the author of that commit, and send them a polite note, to let them know what specific type of error they might want to especially watch out for, next time.

Answer (score 0):

The `git filter-branch` commands family will rewrite history, and they preserve the original timestamps and authors by default.

---

The following command will give you the files modified in the current commit :

```
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=AM HEAD^
```

If you have a "reindent" script, you can feed this list to this script :

```
# let's say you save this script in file /tmp/cleanup-head.sh :
git diff --no-renames --diff-filter=AM HEAD^ | xargs reindent
```

You can now use `cleanup-head.sh` as an action for a "index-filter" :

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '/tmp/cleanup-head.sh && git add -u' <branch1> <branch2> ...
```